# Batch consumers on spring-integration channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have not been able to find in Spring Integration documentation the way how to define outbound channel adapter or gateway which would support consuming of multiple messages at once from PollableChannel.

Is it possible or I have to use aggregators to combine messages to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true. There is really no such a component, because any Messaging is designed to get deal just only with single message at a time do not impact other messages.

One channel may accept different messages from different systems, for different business logic, with different atomicity etc...

The [EIP catalog](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com) doesn't provide something similar, but I think your requirement is like `window` or `buffer` from [Reactive Streams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#window).

Right, `Aggregator` can help here. You just need to have some artificial `correlationKey` (`correlation-strategy-expression="1"`) and provide some `batch` release strategy.

There is some interest [Batcher](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-spring/blob/master/reactor-spring-messaging/src/main/java/reactor/spring/messaging/RingBufferBatchingMessageHandler.java) implementation in the Reactor Spring Extension too.

Answer (score -1):

Spring integration has implementation of MessageChannels for this kinds of queues.
One of the implementations is called "PublishSubscribeChannel" May be this is what you are looking for.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html

Comment: how can PubSubChannel be configured to create a batch of messages for subscriber??

Comment: AFAIK,To say that any type of messaging is designed to deal with Single message is just not right, JMS is Java messaging protocol and clearly defines publishing/subscribe model channels, implementation of which can be found as in, Please see an example project for what i suggested.
[link]https://github.com/benjaminwootton/spring-integration-examples/blob/master/target/classes/publish-subscribe-channel-example.xml